# Positioning a parent element to center it's child on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, css-position

I'm creating a panable and zoomable UI that requires a child object to be centered on the screen however i need to move the parent object to center the child object on screen.

I have the code working at 1x magnification but when i apply a css3 transform to zoom the parent in or out my calculations go awry.

If you change the 1st and 4th elements of the parent elements css transform and the js mult var to say 0.5 or 2 then the calculations are out.

Any help would be appreciated as i have been pulling my hair out over this for days.

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tolks/k7xku606/13/)

Javascript

```
$(function() {

$("#child").click(function(e) {

var mult = 1

$("#parent").css('left',
  (($(window).width() - $("#parent").width()) / 2) +
  ($("#parent").width() * mult) / 2 -
  ($("#child").position().left / mult) -
  ($("#child").width() * mult) / 2
);

$("#parent").css('top',
  (($(window).height() - $("#parent").height()) / 2) +
  ($("#parent").height() * mult) / 2 -
  ($("#child").position().top / mult) -
  ($("#child").height() * mult) / 2
);

})

});
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 230px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: pink
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="testBox" id="child">CLICK ME</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't usually write JS, but I got it working:

```
$(function() {

  $("#child").click(function(e) {

    var mult = 3

    $("#parent").css('left',
        (($(window).width()-$("#child").width()*mult) / 2) -
        $("#child").position().left +
        (mult-1) * $("#parent").width() / 2
    );

    $("#parent").css('top',
        (($(window).height()-$("#child").height()*mult) / 2) -
        $("#child").position().top +
        (mult-1) * $("#parent").height() / 2
    );
  })
});
```

Here are the things that I think might have made it difficult for you (they did for me):

1. `$("#child").position()` gives the position **after** the transform whilst `$("#child").width()` gives the width **before** the transform. that is, with the CSS you posted but with `transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0);` then `$("#child").position().left == 460` but `$("#child").width() == 150`.
2. When setting `$("#parent").css('left', ... )` it is the left offset before the transform and the transform scales around the center. that is, with the CSS you posted but with `transform: matrix(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0);` if you would want to set `#parent`'s left edge to be aligned with the left edge of the window then you have to set `$("#parent").css('left', 175)` and not `$("#parent").css('left', 0)` as I initially expected.

Comment: Thanks so much @psuedoDust it works perfectly. Your description of the position values **after** the transform and the **width** before transform makes sense. I'm slightly confused as to how the (mult-1) part works. I assume it has something to do with transform value less than 1?

Comment: The `(mult-1)` thing has to do with the fact that left is set before the transform, the transform will move the "real" left position of `#parent` by`(mult-1) * $("#parent").width() / 2` to the left because it is scaled around the center. the left you set is `$("#parent").width() / 2` away from the center and the "real" left (after scale) is `mult * $("#parent").width() / 2`, subtract the two and you get your answer.